# Is there a way to detect from Javascript if webpage is open in SFSafariViewController or mobile-safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, uiwebview, mobile-safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

Usually it is easier to detect UIWebViews because their user agent is often different from safari's, but SFSafariViewController use exact same user agent. On newly released iOS 10, I am running into certain HTML5 video issue which is only occurring when page is opened in SFSafariViewController. Is there a way to detect from plain javascript if browser is actually a SFSafariViewController??

Comment: My answer got deleted by stackoverflow for being a duplicate  you can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73353855/1319878