# in iOS, is there a way to detect if a web page is loaded with SFSafariViewController vs the normal Safari Browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is there a way to detect if a web page is loaded with `SFSafariViewController` vs the normal Safari Browser using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of the obscure system font `.Helvetica LT MM` in a canvas. Use the following Github Gist, and then call `isInsideSFSafariViewController()`.

Note that this can break at any time with a new release, so your code should gracefully fall back.

https://gist.github.com/aeharding/08eaafbb7742f78ede9b8d2f5d096354

Answer (score -2):

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
}

@supports not (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  /* CSS for other than iOS devices */ 
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this seems to help us to differentiate between iOS and non iOS, which is not what I'm looking for.